# order theory symbology for "is at the same level as"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, order-theory

Is there a symbol in order theory to express that an element is "equal" in order than another even if both elements are not the *same* element?

Basically: 
$ \exists a,b \in A :  (a \preceq b)  \land (b \preceq a) \land (a \neq b) $

Also, is there a symbol to say two elements are incomparable?

Comment: (a⪯b)∧(b⪯a) implies equality, by definition of order

Comment: i see, what's the definition of order then? i cant seem to find it.
Cant two elements be equal in ordering but different in value?

Comment: An order must be reflexive (a⪯a for all a), antisymmetric ((a⪯b)∧(b⪯a) implies a=b), transitive ((a⪯b)∧(b⪯c) implies  a⪯c) and total (either a⪯b or b⪯a). To have 2 incomparable elements mean you have a partially order set.

Comment: AFAIK orders dont need to be total, you can have a partial and not total order (Poset but not totally ordered set).
However i'm aware that a poset needs to be antisimetric, therefore $a \preceq b \land b \preceq a \Rightarrow a = b$.

What's news to me is that all orders must  be at least posets.

Comment: In general, in English, ordered set is for total order and poset for partially order set. However, I admit this is confusing, and one can use order to talk about any partial or total order. But you cannot take out one of the first 3 axioms without losing precious properties about orders that you need in order theory

Comment: The objects you're interested in are called preorders (at least Wikipedia and one book I checked do so).